# Filter ManyToMany by user from current model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm bit stuck on one stuff.

How I can reach all `Rerservation` from the current `Main` model which belongs to the current user? Any help will be be appreciate

```
   class ReservationPay(generic.DetailView):
        model = Main

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Reservation, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_rea'] = Main.objects.filter(all_resa__user=self.request.user).all()

class Rerservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)

class Main(models.Model):
    all_resa = models.ManyToManyField('Rerservation',blank=True, related_name='all_resa_reservation')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Reserveration.objects.filter(
    user=self.request.user,
    all_resa_reservation=self.object
)
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know I could filter like that :)